# How to detect which operator(Sim1 or Sim2) is providing the mobile data in a device?

Tags: android, dual-sim

I was able to identify whether my device is using Wifi or mobile Data. Now, I'm stuck in identifying the SIM operator who is providing the mobile data in case of a dual SIM device.

```
 NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
   for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if(ni.getDetailedState().toString().toLowerCase().equals("connected")){
            tv.setText(" Typename: "+ni.getTypeName());
            tv.append("\n Detailed state: "+ni.getDetailedState()+"\n Extra Info: "+ni.getExtraInfo()+"\n Type: "+ni.getType()+"\n Reason :"+ni.getReason()
                    +"\n SubType Name :"+ni.getSubtypeName()+"\n SubType :"+ni.getSubtype()+"\n State :"+ni.getState());
            if(!ni.getTypeName().toString().toLowerCase().equals("wifi")){
                tv.append("\n Carrier:"+carrierName);
            }



        }

    }
```

The above code identifies between WIFI and Data. But if the device is using mobile data , and if it is a dual SIM device, how can I identify which of the SIM is providing the mobile data?`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

For API >= 21

From Settings.Global

```
int sim = -1;
SubscriptionManager sm = (SubscriptionManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
if (sm != null) {
   try {
        int id = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "multi_sim_data_call");
        SubscriptionInfo si = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(id);
        if (si != null)
            sim = si.getSimSlotIndex();
       } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }                                                                    
  }
```

or using Reflection

```
int sim = -1;
SubscriptionManager sm = (SubscriptionManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
if (sm != null) {
   try {
        Method mGetDefaultDataSubId = getMethod(sm.getClass(), "getDefaultDataSubscriptionId", 0);
        if (mGetDefaultDataSubId != null) {
            int id = (int) mGetDefaultDataSubId.invoke(sm);
            SubscriptionInfo si = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(id);
            if (si != null)
                sim = si.getSimSlotIndex();                 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                                                    
  }                                                                   
private static Method getMethod (Class c, String name, int params) {
    Method[] cm = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : cm) {
        if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            int length = m.getParameterTypes().length;
            if (length == params)
                return m;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: getActiveSubscriptionInfo() needs READ_PHONE_STATE runtime permission.